Simulating a charging battery in LTSPICE
How would I go about simulating a charging battery in LTSPICE? I've seen these two articles (A Tutorial on Battery Simulation - Matching
Power Source to Electronic System and Accurate electrical battery model capable of predicting runtime and I-V performance) but the models there seem to be more geared towards circuits that are currently being powered  by a battery, where I am working on a circuit that is charging one. Does anyone have an idea of where to get a battery model or how to build an equivalent circuit?

A Google search for Spice battery simulation will show some models.
Below is a simple one I have used for a battery charger load:
R_ser is the battery series resistance, and R_par represents the battery trickle charge current.  C3 in Farads simulates the battery Ah capacity.


Something to maybe note as well is perhaps if the supplier of said battery has a datasheet where there's a mention of its equivalent circuit, that can help as well. Also, a battery's resistance can also increase as it's being depleted more and more. Good answer though +1
